# PHP folder name for Jquery File Upload

Tags: php, jquery, file-upload

I am running my site on a WAMP server, and will upload when done.

As such I want to change the upload DIR of jQuery File Upload code in a generic way so it will work once uploaded.

Is this possible ?

I want to change /server/php/UploadHandler.php as follows:

```
'upload_dir' => dirname($this->get_server_var('SCRIPT_FILENAME')).'/files/',
'upload_url' => $this->get_full_url().'/files/',
```

I want to have these point to:

```
'upload_dir' => base WWW dir . '/proj/wp-content/uploads/folder/'
'upload_url' => base URL . '/proj/wp-content/uploads/folder/'
```

**How do I do this in PHP ?**

Answer (score 0):

Got it! Changed them to:

```
'upload_dir' => $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/proj/wp-content/uploads/folder/',
'upload_url' => $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/proj/wp-content/uploads/folder/',
```